# How many times does the browser download two img elements with the same src?

Tags: html, browser, browser-cache

Two `img` elements with the same `src` attribute.

Does the browser download it once or twice?

Comment: modern browser caches the image resources. so if you using latest chrome or firefox, the browser will download it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the server's caching policy and/or the browser's setting on the client's side; under normal standards an image is only loaded once and used throughout the session (or until temp files are cleared);

You can do a test by loading the same image src twice for example:
http://url/image.png
http://url/image.png

Load your page, and view the browser's temp file directory if you see image.png once or whether you see image[1].png along with the image.png; which means it would've been loaded into your cache twice;

Under normal circumstances, it typically is a one-time load. It all depends on factors that are server and browser based per each instance.

Comment: Apart fron viewing temp directory, one can simply open up Chrome's inspector->network (or equivalent tool in other browsers), you can see the actual request and cache status.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I will always admire high level of stackoverflow user knowledges!